# Slack API not listing new channel

Tags: slack-api

I am writing a Slack application which uses the Python `slack_sdk` to send messages to Slack channels, but checks if they exist first (uses `conversations.list`) - if a channel does not exist, it gets created using `conversations.create`. The problem is that calling the `conversations.list` API returns a list of channels as expected, but the newly-created channel is not included in the list, so subsequent checks by my application show the channel as being non-existent and so `conversations.create` fails with the error message `name taken`.

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Found out the problem to be pagination. `conversations.list` returns a paginated list.